# Laravel Eloquent Where and orWhere with Eager Load not working well

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I've been create JOIN with eager load with these tables

1. Transactions (**parent** of *transaction_details*)
2. Transaction_details (**child** of Transaction and **parent** of *Mutasi_logs* )
3. Mutasi_logs (**child** of *transaction_details*)

then i add some filters such as :

1. **only show my data** (data that has been created by the user logged in)
2. **only show my saldo**
3. **only show my amount**

I've try with this code

```
blahlblah.....
  ->where('created_by',Auth::id())
  ->orWhere('amount','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')
```

->orWhere('saldo','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')

but here where condition not working well (show another user's data like my saldo and amount ) when fill the search field.

here is the output :

[image: search output showing wrong data]

and here my full code :

```
MutasiLog::with([
                 'transaction_detail.transaction',
                ])
                ->orWhereHas('transaction_detail', function (&$q) use ($search) {
                  $q->where('id', 'like', '%' . $search . '%');

                $q->orWhereHas('transaction',function($q) use ($search){
                   $q->where('description','LIKE','%'.$search.'%');
                });
      })
      ->where('created_by',Auth::id())
      ->orWhere('amount','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')
      ->orWhere('saldo','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')
      ->offset($start)
      ->limit($limit)
      ->orderBy($order,$dir)
      ->get();
```

Comment: from the docs "You should always group orWhere calls in order to avoid unexpected behavior when global scopes are applied.". You can find an example [there](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#parameter-grouping)

Comment: SOLVED - thank you :D ... can u put your comment to answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs "You should always group orWhere calls in order to avoid unexpected behavior when global scopes are applied.". You can find an example [there](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#parameter-grouping).
So you can do something like this:

```
// blahlblah.....

        ->where(function ($query) use ($search) {
            $query->where('created_by',Auth::id())
                  ->orWhere('amount','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')
                  ->orWhere('saldo','LIKE','%'.$search.'%');
        })
        // ...
```

Or maybe this, depends on your needs:

```
// blahlblah.....
        ->where('created_by',Auth::id())
        ->where(function ($query) use ($search) {
            $query->where('amount','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')
                  ->orWhere('saldo','LIKE','%'.$search.'%');
        })
        // ...
```

Answer (score 1):

when using orWhere and chained with other wheres, you mean : get data where created_by me or where amount like search , this is why get all data ,so the solution you should group search orWhere on single where like this :

```
      ->where('created_by',Auth::id())
      ->where(function($query){
         $query->orWhere('amount','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')->orWhere('saldo','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')
})
```